# core controller not overidden

Tags: controllers

I want to override `Mage_Sales_Recurring_ProfileController` in my custom module.

My `/etc/config.xml`

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <sales>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Namespace_Module before="Mage_Sales">Namespace_Module</Namespace_Module>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </sales>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

and my controller file

```
Namespace/Module/controllers/Sales/Recurring/ProfileController.php


require_once("Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php");
class Namespace_Module_Sales_Recurring_ProfileController extends Mage_Sales_Recurring_ProfileController
{
   public function indexAction()
    {
       // custom code
    }
}
```

But the control doesnt go in the overriden controller, but the core controller only.

Can anyone tell the reason why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do **one (and just one)** of the following.

1. Put your controller in `Namespace/Module/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php` and name the class `Namespace_Module_Recurring_ProfileController`.  (I recommend this one).
2. Change in `config.xml` this `<Namespace_Module before="Mage_Sales">Namespace_Module</Namespace_Module>` to this `<Namespace_Module before="Mage_Sales">Namespace_Module_Sales</Namespace_Module>`.  You should use this only if you override multiple controllers from multiple modules in your module. This helps you group the controllers better. If you only override controllers from `Mage_Sales`, there is no need to do this. Go with the first approach.